# Can I combine cut commands and use custom delimiters

Tags: text-processing, cut, url

I have log file where I need to extract  URLs from GET requests which have 404d

I have used :

```
grep 404 testfile.txt | cut -f 2 -d '"' | cut -f 2 -d '/' | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | sort -u
```

Is is inadvisable to pipe cut commands together like this, can I combine them into a single line. For example cut from the 3rd "/" and the 6th " ".

Log File Example :

```
ip - - [12/Dec/2019:13:18:00 +0000] "GET /test.html HTTP/1.1" 200 710 "-" "python-requests/2.18.4"

ip - - [12/Dec/2019:13:18:00 +0000] "GET /403dz2.html HTTP/1.1" 404 492 "-" "python-requests/2.18.4"
```

Result :

```
403dz2.html,
is0pmq.html,
iw30ce.html,
nbk0px.html,
```

Comment: awk will do anything that grep, cut, and sed will do, in one process, and with way more maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with piping together `cut` commands like you have done, however, you should be aware that on large inputs there may be more efficient ways of doing this operation. This is because in your example the input file must be processed by a command 5 times before it is output to the terminal (once for `grep` filtering, three separate `cut` parsing commands, and once to `sort`). Using less pipes *may* improve performance, but this ultimately depends on the commands themselves and what operations they perform (ie, three quick and simple operations are faster than one large high computation operation). If the input data is relatively small though, it makes no difference whether you use your method of piping or one of the following below.

***Note:*** I am not sure on the efficiency or speed of the following examples when compared to the OP's original command chain. Depending on the use case, some may be "better" than others.

**Using `awk`:** *(recommended)*

```
awk '$9=="404" {print substr($7,2)","}' testfile.txt
```

The above is similar to Romeo's answer, however this additionally removes the preceding slash from the filename in the log output and adds the comma at the end, to match your desired result. `awk` is a command that parses input data (by default) line by line, splitting each line (by default) on the space separator. This command checks the 9th field (HTTP response code) for `404` and if it matches it takes the substring of the 7th field from the 2nd character to the end (`substr($7,2)`), and appends a comma to that (`","`) before printing the output. You can read more about `awk` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

**Using your example with one `cut` + `sed`:**

```
grep '" 404' testfile.txt | cut -d' ' -f7 | sed 's/\///; s/$/,/'
```

You don't need three separate cut commands to extract the filename, you only need one when using the space delimiter. The `cut` command will pull the string `/403dz2.html`. `sed` will then take that, remove the preceding slash (`s/\///`), and then add a comma to the end (`s/$/,/`). What `sed` is *actually* doing here is substituting. The string `s/replace this/with this/` tells `sed` to substitute the string first string (`replace this`) with the second (`with this`). The first substitute command instructs `sed` to replace `/` with nothing, and the second says to "replace" the end of the line (`$`) with `,`. You can read more about `sed` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Also note that I am `grep`ing for `" 404`, this is sort of hacky but it will keep `grep` from returning lines where 404 appears elsewhere (like the filename, file size, date, etc).

**Using `perl`:**

```
grep '" 404' testfile.txt | perl -lane 'print substr($F[6],1).","'
```

This is similar to the `awk` example, while using `grep` to filter the input. Using the same idea as with `awk`, we are printing the substring of the 7th field (`substr($F[6],1)`) and appending a comma to this output (`.","`). Be aware that perl starts counting from zero while awk begins counting from 1, hence the reason we are using `$F[6]` in `perl` to pull the 7th field where as `$7` is used in awk. The `perl` manual can be found [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to filter with delimiter space ()?

```
awk '$9=="404" {print $7}' testfile.txt|sort -u
```

Or with this:

```
grep 404 testfile.txt | cut -f 7 -d ' '|sort -u
```

P.S. The second way will match when for example the length of download is 404 bytes. Or year contain 404 string. Or requested URL contain this string.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` command:

```
awk -F '[ /]' '/ 404 / {print $10|"sort -u"}' testfile.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-F '[ /]'` : use spaces " " and forward slash "/" as delimiters. (multiple delimiter)
- `/ 404 /` : only match lines that contain " 404 ". Just like `grep " 404 " testfile.txt` works.

**Note**: there is some spacing before and after " 404 ".

This eliminates any false positives matches that might be appearing in the URL instead of the Response code. For Instance, the following line will NOT be matched:

`ip - - [12/Dec/2019:13:18:00 +0000] "GET /test404.html HTTP/1.1" 200 710 "-" "python-requests/2.18.4"`

**Note**: **test404.html** URL contains **404** but the response code is **200**. Hence the need for spacing before and after " 404 ".

- `print $10` : using spaces and slashes as delimiter, display the 10th field.
- `| sort -u`  : sort the results, only taking one instance where there is a duplicate.(i.e display Unique lines)
- `testfile.txt` : the file containing the lines to be matched.

**Note**: Assuming there are other lines with `404` but are not of interest, you can tighten the matching by using the following:

```
awk -F '[ /]' '/GET.* 404 / {print $10|"sort -u"}' testfile.txt
```

**What Has Been Modified:**

- `/GET.* 404 /` : only match lines that contain "`GET` followed by other stuff, then `404`"

**FINALLY:**

- If You want the SLASH before the URL, use:

  ```
  awk '/ 404 / {print $7|"sort -u"}' testfile.txt
  ```
- if You want the COMMA after the URL, use:

  ```
  awk -F '[ /]' '/ 404 / {print $10","|"sort -u"}' testfile.txt
  ```
- If You want BOTH the SLASH before the URL and COMMA after the URL use:

  ```
  awk '/ 404 / {print $7","|"sort -u"}' testfile.txt
  ```